# "\n" not adding new line when saving the string to text using PrintWriter

Tags: java, newline, printwriter

I want to print a string to a text using `out.print` but the `\n` in the string are not working.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class LetterRevisited{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Test.txt");
        out.println("This is the first line\n" +
        "This is the second line" );
    out.close();
    }
}
```

But in the saved file no new line is created, all the lines are after each other.
Any idea how to fix this? (beside adding `out.println` to all lines.)

Edit: I compile and run the code with windows command prompt and open the file with notepad.

Comment: On which platform are you running this code?

Comment: And how are you think determining whether or not there are newlines? (Hint: on Windows, tools like Notepad need `\r\n`.)

Comment: you probably shouldn't use println. Also try '\r\n'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Different platforms use different line separators.

- Windows use `\r\n`
- Unix-like platforms use `\n`
- Mac now uses `\n` too, but it used to use `\r`.

(You can see more information and variants [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline))

You can get your "local" line separator by using

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

e.g.

```
out.println("Hello" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "World");
```

However, it is easier to use `%n` in a string formatter:

```
out.printf("Hello%nWorld%n");
```

If you are targeting a particular platform, you can just use the literal.

Comment: Thanks to Andy Turner After he said \n IS for windows I opened the file with wordpad and it was alright.

The problem was with the notepad only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 7 then you can use System.lineSeparator()..see if this helps. For older versions of Java you can use - System.getProperty("line.separator")

Example :
System.out.println(System.lineSeparator()+"This is the second line");